# Enter DateTime in SQL

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have a question and I have a Rebirth Script for a game functions 2 things are not so perfect and indeed the

First Funktion.: DateTime here is the code

I have IIS and PHP v7.2.21

```
$old_date = date_format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$new_date = date_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $old_date_timestamp);

    and ($old_date_timestamp->rRebirthDate == strtotime($old_date))

    $db_enter_rRebirthDate = $new_date->rRebirthDate < date_format("Y-m-d H:i:s");


    if($db_select_chars_trebirthinfo_save[0]->rRebirthNo == 0)
    {
        $db_enter_syntax_trebirthinfo = "
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tRebirthInfo]
            (
                nCharNo,rRebirthDate,rRebirthNo
            )
            VALUES
            (
                '".$_POST['character']."','".$db_enter_rRebirthDate."','".$db_enter_rRebirthNo."'
            )
        ";
    }
    else
    {
        $db_enter_syntax_trebirthinfo = "
            UPDATE
                [dbo].[tRebirthInfo]
            SET
                rRebirthDate='".$db_enter_rRebirthDate."',
                rRebirthNo='".$db_enter_rRebirthNo."'
            WHERE
                nCharNo='".$_POST['character']."'
        ";
    }
```

so that's the script

I can handle a date in the SQL database but only this one

1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

I'm doing something wrong maybe?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: there are syntax errors above, so its hard to work out whats going on. whats this line suppose to mean: `and ($old_date_timestamp->rRebirthDate == strtotime($old_date))` ?

Comment: meaning your getting `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` date instead of the current date or he date of your choice?, the question is not clear

Comment: i just get this date 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 instead of the current date but why

Comment: and ($old_date_timestamp->rRebirthDate == strtotime($old_date))

there the old date is read out then